# how to warm start my SciPy.Optimize.Minimize function with previously calculated gradient as initial guess

Tags: python, scipy, neural-network

I'm using the `scipy.optimize.minimize` method using `Newton-CG` to minimize a Neural Network cost. The cost function implements back propagation algorithm. I have parallelized the cost function to scale up for larger volumes of samples.

Now, for any reason if the optimization breaks after certain iterations and does not complete successfully, I would like to restart the process not from beginning, but with the gradient computed in the previous step.

I'm trying this by 1) saving the gradient in the cost function before it returns. 2) use the saved gradient as the initial guess when I restart the optimization.

This approach does not work. The cost does not start from where it left in the previous run. It's roughly about 10 time....

I'm trying to see through the source code of `scipy.optimize.minimize` to understand how the initial_guess is using, but no luck yet.

Comment: `I would like to restart the process not from beginning, but with the gradient computed in the previous step.` - I don't get this part. You always start with an initial `x` value. The gradient at `x` is determined by your function. Did you try to pass a gradient to `x0`? This obviously won't work. Try passing the `x` value instead. Please consider adding some code to your question. At the moment it's very hard to guess the problem.

Comment: Perhaps look into http://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/

Comment: Hi There, Thanks a lot for the response.

Comment: I solved the issue. the mistake in my approach and solution: The cost function receives an initial_grad and set of parameters and returns cost and Grad. I was saving the "Grad" and using it as the initial guess when I restart. Instead I should save the initial_grad  received by the cost function. This solved the problem.